# cloud formation template for s3 in existing VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I tried deploying new s3 bucket in existing vpc using cloud formation template with the help of aws docs, but I am getting error "**Encountered unsupported property VpcConfiguration.**" below is my yaml

Resources:

S3Bucket:
Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

```
Properties:
  AccessControl: PublicRead
  Tags:
    - Key: Name
      Value: My Bucket
  BucketName: !Ref BucketName
  PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
      BlockPublicAcls: false
      BlockPublicPolicy: false
      IgnorePublicAcls: false
      RestrictPublicBuckets: false
  VpcConfiguration:
     VpcId: vpc-aexxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type: AWS::S3::Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html) does not have a property called `VpcConfiguration`.

I think you meant [AWS::S3::AccessPoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-accesspoint.html) which indeed has [VpcConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-accesspoint.html#cfn-s3-accesspoint-vpcconfiguration).

Comment: yes I mixed both. thanks. However I want to create new s3 bucket in existing vac. but the accessPoint only be created for existing bucket. Hence I get error while using Type: AWS::S3::AccessPoint.